# Chrome extention: inject js code to get the arrays written in ng-repeat tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

[I want to get the array "chatContent" to calculate the number of message and the content of the message. What should I do?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKbgw.png)

Comment: try ; `{{ ChatContent.length }}`

Comment: What if I want to get the element in "ChatContent"

Comment: use the index of the element  or some unique fields likw message id